# Match a word with space beside

Tags: javascript, regex, match, whitespace, space

I'm trying to match the following examples (javascript):

1.- "dog dogs"
**R**- match **dog** = true

2.- "dogsdogs"
**R**- match **dog**= false

3.- "cat dog dogs dogdogs dog"
**R** - match **dog**(twice) = true

4.- "cat dog$dog"
**R**- match **dog**= false

5.- "cat dog\ndog" OR "cat dog\sdog" 
 
**R**- match **dog**(twice) = true

6.- "catdog dog $dog$dog dog"
**R**- math **dog**(twice) = true

I've just got this /\b(dog)\b/g but if i use this /^(dog)$/g just match one word

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain the desired behavior better? Example 5 allows `\s` instead of a space, so it may accept any sequence of whitespace?

Comment: Example 1 and 3 conflict, in my mind. If 'dog' matches 'dogs' because `dog` is contained within `dog`s, then example 3 should match 'dog' in: `dog`, `dog`s, `dog`dogs (or dog`dog`s), and `dog`. How are you prioritizing when a word matches?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Exmple 5 accept \n and \s. I must update it. 1 and 3 must match just if theres no charachters or symbols beside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/(^|\s)(dog)(?=\s|$)/gm
```

Tested via regexr - http://regexr.com?38gla

This matches a start of string or whitespace, then the word dog, then whitespace or end of string. The trailing whitespace/end of string is a positive lookahead, so its not consumed, allowing that space to be used for another match - ex "cat dog dog"